# Cannot import fastparquet into Python notebook

Tags: python, python-import, parquet, fastparquet

I am trying to install `fastparquet` in order to convert a pandas dataframe into a parquet file. But even though I get the following when i run `pip install fastparquet`

```
Requirement already satisfied: fastparquet in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.19 in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.28 in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (0.43.1+0.g8dabe7abe.dirty)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (1.16.3)
Requirement already satisfied: thrift>=0.11.0 in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->fastparquet) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->fastparquet) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite>=0.28.0dev0 in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.28->fastparquet) (0.28.0)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.28->fastparquet) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.28->fastparquet) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs in c:\users\avant\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.28->fastparquet) (1.0.2)
```

when I try importing it in my Jupyter notebook - the following error is shown:

`ImportError: cannot import name unpack_byte_array`

Moreover, I have also looked into `pyarrow` but am unable to install it properly due to conflicts between packages.

Comment: Are you using the correct name when importing the package? Do you have multiple environments specified in your Anaconda? If yes, have you installed the module in question in the right one?

Comment: As you are using `anaconda` for your Python environment, I strongly recommend to use `conda` to create environments and install packages. This should avoid such errors and also give you better feedback on why neither fastparquet nor pyarrow work for you.