# Unable to import fastparquet in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, fastparquet

Similar questions as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921602/cannot-import-fastparquet-into-python-notebook). But my error reports

 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastparquet'`

 When I run `conda list` under the same virtual environment, I get 
[image]

 However, I'm able to `import fastparquet` when I'm in the interactive dialogue in "cmd" prompt by calling `python` directly. (See below)
[image]

Comment: Which python interpreter is conda and jupyter using?

Comment: I used ```import platform; platform.python_implementation()``` and it returns ```'CPython'```

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question. Which path on your system does that point to? You're using windows, so did you somehow install both python and Anaconda separately?

Comment: Yes. I installed python and Anaconda separately. I had installed python before I installed Anaconda. When I execute ```where python``` on my cmd prompt, I get <br> ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe``` <br> ```C:\Users\<my name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe```

Comment: And which one of those is jupyter using?

Comment: In jupyter notebook, after I execute ```import sys; print(sys.executable)```. I get ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe```. So, I think it's ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe```? Thanks